# Postfix allows unauthenticated users to send emails

Tags: email, debian, smtp, postfix, sasl

Hey I set up Postfix to use `cyrus` SASL implantation and I'm able to login and send emails, but I can still telnet on port 25 and send mails even if I'm not authenticated, which I whish to deny.

`smtp_sasl` part of my `main.cf`:

```
smtpd_sasl_path = smtpd
smtpd_sasl_type = cyrus
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = reject_non_fqdn_recipient, reject_non_fqdn_sender, reject_unlisted_recipient, permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination, reject_invalid_hostname, reject_unknown_sender_domain, reject_unknown_recipient_domain, reject_rbl_client, sbl-xbl.spamhaus.org, reject_rbl_client, bl.spamcop.net, reject_rbl_client, list.dsbl.org, reject_rbl_client, rbl.mail-abuse.org, reject_rbl_client, spamsources.fabel.dk
```

*Full config [here](http://paste.debian.net/94209/)*

Did I forgot something?

**Telnet Log:**

```
=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~= PuTTY log 2014.04.20 16:10:32 =~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=
220 the999ers.eu ESMTP Postfix (Debian/GNU)
ehlo kim-nuernberger.eu
250-the999ers.eu
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 10240000
250-VRFY
250-ETRN
250-STARTTLS
250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
250-AUTH=PLAIN LOGIN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250 DSN
MAIL FROM: test@kim-nuernberger.eu
250 2.1.0 Ok
RCPT TO: trash@kim-nuernberger.eu
DATA
250 2.1.5 Ok
354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>
Subject: test
This is a test mail
.
250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as B82481DF1CE
quit
221 2.0.0 Bye
```

this was captured from my *local* pc and I connected via my domain `kim-nuernberger.eu`.

**Postfix log (/var/log/mail.log)**

```
Apr 20 16:31:37 The999ers postfix/smtpd[16420]: connect from unknown[2a03:4000:2:206::1]
Apr 20 16:31:57 The999ers postfix/smtpd[16420]: 25CED1DF1CE: client=unknown[2a03:4000:2:206::1]
Apr 20 16:32:13 The999ers postfix/cleanup[16425]: 25CED1DF1CE: message-id=<20140420143157.25CED1DF1CE@kim-nuernberger.eu>
Apr 20 16:32:13 The999ers postfix/qmgr[16407]: 25CED1DF1CE: from=<test@kim-nuernberger.eu>, size=385, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Apr 20 16:32:14 The999ers postfix/smtp[16426]: 25CED1DF1CE: to=<trash.kim.nuernberger@hotmail.de>, orig_to=<trash@kim-nuernberger.eu>, relay=mx4.hotmail.com[65.55.37.104]:25, delay=25, delays=23/0.01/0.47/1.1, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250  <20140420143157.25CED1DF1CE@kim-nuernberger.eu> Queued mail for delivery)
Apr 20 16:32:14 The999ers postfix/qmgr[16407]: 25CED1DF1CE: removed
Apr 20 16:32:14 The999ers postfix/smtpd[16420]: disconnect from unknown[2a03:4000:2:206::1]
```

*Note: I updated the log after fixing some unnecessary problems.*

Comment: What address are you "telnetting" from, and to?

Comment: @grawity I telnet from my local adress to my domain, or did you mean somethig different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because you might have tried to send mail from the server(i.e `telnet localhost 25`) itself and in your `smtpd_recipient_restrictions` `permit_mynetworks` comes before `permit_sasl_authenticated` and so the clients listed in `mynetworks` (`localhost` in your case) need not authenticate. Rearrange the restrictions to achieve what you want.

More info: [postfix docs](http://www.postfix.org/SMTPD_ACCESS_README.html)

Edit 1:

Thanks for the telnet and postfix logs. postfix will not require authentication to receive mails for the domains it handle under `mydestination`,`relay_domains` `virtual_alias_domains` and `virtual_mailbox_domains`. Users will not be able to `relay` to external domains(i.e the domains that are remote. eg. gmail.com) unless they authenticate and this is the expected behaviour.

Comment: Well I open the telnet connection from my local pc and connect via the domain (kim-nuernberger.eu in this case) to the server, so this shouldn't happen, right?

Comment: Can you give the IP address or it's prefix of your local pc and your server?

Comment: Even removing `permit_mynetworks` doesn't work at all..

Comment: can you update the question with the `telnet` command that worked and the postfix log lines generated for the same?

Comment: Okay I added my local telnet log and the postfix log from the server.

Comment: Hey postfix will not require authentication to receive mails for the domains it handle under `mydestination`,`relay_domains` `virtual_alias_domains` and `virtual_mailbox_domains`. Users will not be able to relay to external domains(i.e the domains that are remote. eg. gmail.com) unless they authenticate and this is the expected behaviour.

Comment: Okay I got it - I was sending mails to the server it self the whole time and didn't tried another relay.. When you write a new answer I will accept it and give it the bounty. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You can force users to authenticate before send e-mails, changing not on the main.conf but on master.conf, adding the check on submission, for example, and reject everything:

```
-o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
```

This was 4 years ago, but maybe will help new people.

Comment: Thanks for keeping the next one in mind :)